# Why am I getting a UNIQUE constraint error in sqlite?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a bank account management system where the user can create an account, log in, and withdraw/deposit money from that account.

```
# PHASE 1 (FILE I/O and Logic of System)
# Initialization of Current Balance ** Current Balance is the same for all users for the sake of simplicity ** 
myMoney = open("current_balance.txt")
currentBalance = int(myMoney.readline())

# Imports 
import sqlite3
# Creation of Bank Account and Notifying User(s) of Current Balance
class Bank_Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance= currentBalance
        print("Welcome to Your Bank Account System!")
    # If statements for first screen
    def options_1(self):
        ch = int(input("1. Create an Account\n2. Log into Your Account\nEnter a Choice: "))
        if ch == 1: 
            self.create()
        if ch == 2: 
            self.Log_in()
    def options_2(self): 
        ch= int(input("1. Withdraw Money from Your Account\n2. Deposit Money to Your Account\nEnter a Choice: "))
        if ch == 1: 
            self.withdraw()
        if ch == 2: 
            self.deposit()
    # Function to Create an Account 
    def create(self): 
        user_create_input = str(input("Enter a Username:"))
        pin_create_input = int(input("Enter a Pin Number:" ))
        print("Account successfully created!")
     # Function to Log into Account 
    def Log_in(self):
        user_input = str(input("Enter your Username:"))
        pin_input = int(input("Enter your Pin Number:")) 
        print("Welcome", user_input, "!")
    # Function to Deposit Money 
    def deposit(self):
        amount=float(input("Enter the amount you want to deposit: "))
        self.balance += amount
        print("Amount Deposited: ",amount)
    # Function to Withdraw Money
    def withdraw(self):
        amount = float(input("Enter the amount you want to withdraw: "))
        if self.balance>=amount:
            self.balance-=amount
            print("You withdrew: ",amount)
        else:
            print("Insufficient balance ")

    def display(self):
        print("Net Available Balance=",self.balance)

# PHASE 2 (With Database) SQLite 3 

# Define Connection and Cursor 
connection = sqlite3.connect('Bank_Users.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()


# Create Users Table 
command1 = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
bank(pin INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username text )"""
cursor.execute(command1)

# Add to Users/Bank
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (7620, 'Kailas Kurup')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (4638, 'Bethany Watkins')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (3482, 'John Hammond')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (3493, 'Melissa Rodriguez')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES (9891, 'Kevin Le')")

# Get Results / Querying Database
cursor.execute("SELECT username, pin FROM bank")
results = cursor.fetchall() 
print(results)
connection.commit()
# Check Database User Info  
def Log_in2():
        user_input = str(input("Enter your Username:"))
        pin_input = int(input("Enter your Pin Number:")) 
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            if user_input and pin_input in row:
                print ("Welcome", user_input, "!")
        else: 
            print("Invalid Login Credentials")
Log_in2()



# Phase 3 (With GUI) Tkinter 

# Creating an object of class
self = Bank_Account()
# Calling functions with that class
self.options_1()
self.options_2()
self.display()
```

QUESTIONS:

The code I wrote underneath the "# Check Database User Info" isn't checking the user input. When a pin or username that is entered which is not in the database should return "Invalid Credentials" How do I fix this?

Why is this UNIQUE Constraint error happening and what do I do to fix it?

Comment: If the table already exists, you don't recreate it. So the second time you run your script you'll try to insert the same pins as the previous time. Since it's declared to be a primary key, you can't have duplicate pins, so you get an error.

Comment: If you want to start over from scratch, you should drop the table first. `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bank`

Comment: @Barmar So if I want to rerun my code to see if it works without this error occuring, I need to drop table? I tried entering the drop table command and I'm getting the following error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kaila\Desktop\Project BA_2\script.py", line 63, in <module>
    cursor.execute(command1)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: There shouldn't be a `(` in the `DROP TABLE` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
if user_input and pin_input in row:
```

is not the correct way to test of the two inputs are both in `row`. It's parsed as:

```
if user_input and (pin_input in row):
```

Also, you can't call `cursor.fetchall()` twice for the same query. `cursor.fetchall()` only fetches the rows that haven't been fetched yet. Once you call it, all rows have been fetched, so there's nothing left to fetch. If you want to loop over the query results multiple times, you should save the result of `fetchall()` in a list and use that.

But there's no need to loop over all the rows to tell if the user input is in the table. Get the user input first, and use it in the `WHERE` clause of the query.

```
def Log_in2():
    user_input = str(input("Enter your Username:"))
    pin_input = int(input("Enter your Pin Number:")) 
    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bank WHERE username = ? AND pin = ?", (user_input, pin_input))
    (count,) = cursor.fetchone()
    if count == 1:
        print ("Welcome", user_input, "!")
    else: 
        print("Invalid Login Credentials")
```